# Why did Drax call Gamora a whore?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, character-motivation, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

> Drax: You, Quill, are my friend. This dumb tree is my friend. And this green whore is now my...
>
> Gamora: You must stop!

Drax's statement seems incongruous with reality and his character.

- There isn't so much as single kiss in the entire movie, including involving Gamora.
- Drax's speech is precise and literal.
- Drax isn't generally disrespectful toward women
- Gamora resists Peter's advances, saying that she isn't one of the dumb girls he seduces.
- While Gamora's attire is not entirely modest, it is not out of the norm either. (Drax himself is half-naked throughout the entire movie.)
- At the time he says this, Drax has no motivation to disparage Gamora. His only intention could be honesty.
- In jail, Rocket suggests Gamora work out an "exchange" with the guards for a control device, since they find her attractive. Gamora says, "You must be joking."

Why did Drax call Gamora a whore?

Comment: Note that the most literal meaning of “whore” is “prostitute”, i.e. someone who has sex in exchange for money. So Gamora’s clothes, response to Peter’s sexual advances, and prison-break tactics aren’t relevant as evidence of whether “whore” is an accurate term.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, she was clearly uncomfortable with using sex for getting her way. While these points couldn't be conclusive proof one way or the other, my point is that Drax's comment seemed to have no basis, so I searched for all the related evidence I could, no matter how circumstantial.

Comment: sure, I just like to think that Drax is literal enough for “whore” to just mean “has sex for money” to him, without any gender-specific (or indeed non-gender-specific) judgmental stuff getting mixed in with it. Your points do illustrate your question well.

Comment: In the comics, Gamora has actually been with almost every member of the Guardians(Groot and Rocket not withstanding). So, it is quite possible that even though they didn't show it in the movie, it could still be a reference to her promiscuity.

Comment: Can we also add to the list that Drax's people is very open when it comes to sex, his parents regularly told him the story of his conception as a child and he considers it beautiful.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

#### Because the prisoners were calling Gamora a "green whore" when she first entered the prison yard, and Drax is incredibly literal. He has no clue they were using it as an insult; he thinks that's what she actually was.

- The problem is if you weren't really listening it was easy to miss,there was a lot going on in that scene.
- When Drax says it again later in the scene you mention, it is far away enough from the initial event, it may not even register as part of a running gag and can come off extremely insensitive to Gamora (and movie viewers who watched her).

**Writer/director James Gunn has answered this question:**

> **[Gunn on Drax calling Gamora a whore](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=58710):** I know some of you don't like Drax calling Gamora a whore. But he heard people saying that to her in the Kyln. So don't blame him, blame me... Because that's what they called her in the Kyln and that's what he thinks she is.

Comment: Wow. That was a stretch.

Comment: I happened to watch the movie again, but I didn't catch it. I'll have to watch it with pause/rewind available.

Comment: Note that in the same conversation (in which he's listing off the people he considers *friends*) he also says something pretty insulting about Groot, for much the same reason.

Comment: Very nice spot :)

Comment: James Gunn went on the record last week to say [that your answer is exactly correct](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=58710).

Answer (score 0):

> Whore, noun:
>
> [Definition of WHORE](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whore)
>
> 1 : A woman who engages in sexual acts for money :  prostitute ; also :  a promiscuous or immoral woman
> 2 : A male who engages in sexual acts for money
> 3 : A venal or unscrupulous person
> <sub><sup>Merriam-Webster Dictionary</sup></sub>

If Drax does truly say things literally he would have said it in the third definition of this word. He believed that she was a venal or unscrupulous person

In reference to her background, how many she has killed, who raised her, it would all make sense that it fits the third definition.

Comment: Many dictionaries do not include the third definition.

Comment: merriam-webster is the definition i have taken, and the oxford dictionary is also another that plays closely to that definition         

"oxford:Debase oneself by doing something for unworthy motives, typically to make money"

Comment: A definition of whore should definitely include the version: "debase oneself by doing something for unworthy motives, typically to make money". Does Gamora do anything unscrupulous for money, or something else? I forget.

Comment: Drax didn't know the meaning of "thesaurus", nor was he cognizent of what a "metaphor" is.  He has formal diction, but not a high level of comprehension.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Not sure how much of Gamora's backstory is widely known, but one could make the case of her working for Thanos as being a "debasement" for the "unworthy motive" of survival after Thanos killed her parents. Drax would (and does) prefer to die avenging his family, and even Gamora clearly thinks working for Thanos is demeaning or objectionable.  If Drax knows her full story (I forget if he does), he could easily call her a whore, based on your definition, for serving the man who killed her family.

Comment: In common language, someone that whores themselves (or is whored out) doesn't have to be for sex. "Thanos whored Gamora out for the Infinity Stone."